# How can I archive same window visible in a specific tag(s) in DWM?

Tags: window-manager, init, dwm

For example, I'm currently in tag 1, now <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is moving the window to tag 2. <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to make/unmake a window “sticky” (follows you from tag to tag)

With <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> the window will be visible in tag 1 and tag 2 at the same time. Sort of stick to a specific tag which I can close.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying to describe is adding or removing a tag to the focused window.

By default, DWM uses <kbd>Mod1</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> keybind for the action.

You can read about this in `man dwm`. There's also [useful guide](https://ratfactor.com/dwm) for a more visual representation.